# Find Cartesian equation of $r=\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

I solved this problem, but I'm not sure my answer is correct as it seems very complex (compared to the polar equation). Did I make some mistake along the way or is it the right solution?

$$r=\theta$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\arctan\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg) \tag{$r^2=x^2+y^2 \to r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$}$$
$$x^2+y^2 = \bigg(\arctan\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg)\bigg)^2$$

Comment: You have your $x$ and $y$ backwards in arctan, but other than that, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. Is it right that this is the equation of a spiral?

Comment: Also just to eliminate any ambiguity, the entire arctan term should be squared in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that too. By the way, how do I mark this question as answered if there are only comments?

Comment: You didn't change the position of the $x$ and $y$ in your first arctan but after that, you're fine. That's as far as this will simplify, I'm afraid. It's a transcendental equation so there's no way to isolate variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\quad r^2 = \theta^2\quad$ expressed as a Cartesian equation is

$$x^2+y^2 = \bigg(\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\bigg)^2$$

But  better yet, for $r = \theta$, use: $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + k\pi\tag{see alex's explanation}$$

ADDED: This is the graph I get (from Wolfram) for the function: using a polar plot.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, fixed. One more question: is it a spiral?

Comment: You're welcome! See the graphs I added: the first plots $y$ given $x$, the second, r, given theta. So in the second graph, we have the "theta" axis and the "r axis"

Comment: OK, but now let's say, for the sake of argument, that you are insane and wish to generate that spiral from a Cartesian expression.  How would you do it, knowing that blind use of arctan will give you the incorrect plot you just had?

Comment: Graph $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \arctan{y/x}$, as the OP originally had. It doesn't give the same plot as the polar plot, of course, but I can insert it if you wish..

Comment: @alex You've done a nice job explaining the nuances of this function. I will correct the need for the tailing $k\pi$.

Comment: @amWhy: I like when I can use graphics too! +1

Answer (score 5):

$\arctan$ is a tricky function. Remember, $\arctan(\tan(\theta))$ does not always equal $\theta$. Sometimes $$\theta=\arctan(\tan(\theta))+k\pi$$

The Cartesian version of your equation is $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+k\pi$$ over all integer values of $k$. Or more concisely:$$\tan\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y}{x}$$
But even this equation doesn't capture the points on the spiral that are on the $y$-axis, where $x=0$ and $y=\pi/2+k\pi$ cause neither of the two sides to be defined. This can be "fixed" by declaring that any pairs$(x,y)$ causing both sides to be undefined should also be included in the curve. All such points are of the form $(0,\pi/2+k\pi)$.

Comment: +1 I attributed my edit to your nuanced explanation. ;-)

Comment: @amWhy I deleted my comment. It was false anyway ;)