# How to convert this polar equation to cartesian?

Tags: polar-coordinates

$r=\cos \left(\frac{13}{7}\theta \right)$

When I try I get this:
$\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{.5}=\space \cos \left(\frac{13\space }{7\space }\arctan \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)$

But that doesn't seem to graph properly, see: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vjyhgdcxkz

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also having trouble converting r=θ

There's lots of ways to do it but:
$\frac{x}{\cos \left(\arctan \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)}=\arctan \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

does not graph right either.  I'm guessing this has something to do with function domains - and I'm otherwise doing this right?

Comment: according to this the issue might just be with desmos: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372863/find-cartesian-equation-of-r-theta?rq=1